# Creating a 5 star product review with PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on a 5 stars products review for a website using php and MySQL, everything works great except my total stars,
When the review is submitted the customer can only add from 1 to 5 stars (no .5) then I'm summing the rating of each review and dividing it by the number of reviews. Now the proble is I need to get either 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5 and so on and sometimes I'll get something like 3.66768748.

How can I round the number so that if it's below if it's more that .5 it will be the ceil, if it's .5 it stays as is and if it's less than .5 it will floor it?

Is there a built in function that I can use for this?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The following function will round to whichever is closest - the next lowest integer, the next highest integer, *or* the halfway point between them.

```
function half_star_round($input) {
    $frac = $input - floor($input);
    if($frac < 0.25) {
        return floor($input);
    } else if($frac >= 0.75) {
        return ceil($input);
    } else {
        return floor($input) + 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this answer was what you were looking for, you can click the green checkmark outline next to it to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

This works. Pass the value you want to be rounded to in the second arg. In your case *0.5*

```
function roundTo($value, $roundTo = 1) {
    $rounded = round($value); // 4
    $roundToComparer = $roundTo / 2;

    if ($value < $rounded) { // rounded to ceiling
        if (($rounded - $roundToComparer) > $value) {
            $rounded = $rounded - $roundTo;
        }
    } else { // rounded to floor
        if (($rounded + $roundToComparer) < $value) {
            $rounded = $rounded + $roundTo;
        }
    }

    return $rounded;
}

$rating = 3.66768748;
echo roundTo($rating, 0.5);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Take the sum of the reviews
2. Divide by the total reviews
3. Multiply by two
4. Round
5. Divide by two

Answer (score -1):

Php proveide round function for that.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Please actually read the OP's question, given that `round()` does not fit what they're asking for.